# Autoformat Excel worksheet Name VBA MS Access 2013

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I am trying to autoformat how the bottom of an Excel page appears in order to automatically view the whole worksheet name. By default, half of the worksheet name is cut off because the horizontal scrollbar near the bottom of the page is too large. By dragging it over I can then view the entire worksheet name.

Instead of having to go into excel and doing this manually, is there a way to do this in VBA? I am using MS Access to export data to these excel files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the scroll bar width using the `TabRatio` property of the `Window` object. The values are between 0 and 1 and the larger the value, the smaller the scrollbar width. For example:

```
xlApp.Activewindow.Tabratio = 0.9
```

Comment: i have this line of code:   Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")  and then I tried adding your code after but changed xlApp to appExcel. but I get an Error 91 saying "Object variable or With block variable not set". What is necessary in order for me to use that?